# Store the same asset in multiple catalogs (Asset Browser)

Tags: asset-browser

**Is it possible to store a single asset in multiple catalogs in Blender's asset browser?**

I have a **dirt** material, and I want to store it in a catalog named **dirt**, and another catalog named, **ground.**

Once I've added the dirt material as an asset, I drag the dirt material into the dirt catalog I've made, then I click back on the all, to show all assets, and then drag the dirt material into the ground catalog. But when I click back on the dirt catalog, its no longer there, because I moved it to the ground catalog. Is it possible to assign the dirt material to multiple catalogs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. They have a "folder" structure, as opposed to "collections". From the [*Blender Wiki*](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Architecture/Asset_System/Catalogs):

> An asset can be assigned a catalog. Similar to files on disk, where a file can only exist in a single directory at a time (ignoring hard-links), **an asset can only be associated with a single catalog at a time.**

[image]<sub>*Image from [the manual entry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/asset_libraries/catalogs.html#asset-catalogs) for Asset Catalogs*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the info ‍